# PowerShell gather info

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm looking for a way to read csv file for header 'Customer' and 'Cars ID'. Issue is I have duplicate customer. I need to find a way to list each unique customer and all its cars id with it. If possible to export it as CustomerName and list all cars id under it. So if I have 3 unique customer, each customer will be export separately.

```
#Get unique customer
$GetUniqCustomer = Import-Csv $File |
                   Sort-Object {$_.customer} -Unique |
                   Select {$_.customer}
```

From here on I'm not sure how I would do what I've described.

This will list all carid under the specific.

```
Import-Csv $File | Where-Object {
    $_.customer -eq $Customer
} | Select {$_."carid"}
```

Comment: All of this is possible. SO is not a free code writing service. Please post the code you have tried and, if needed, someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular scenario you want to use [`Group-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) rather then `Sort-Object -Unique`. Build new custom object from the grouped information and export them to the output CSV file.

```
Import-Csv $File | Group-Object customer | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        Customer = $_.Name
        Cars     = ($_.Group | Select-Object -Expand carid) -join ';'
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: @JohnHang That's not possible unless you changed something aout the code or your input data is not what you said it is.